# Intel parallel studio 2017 is integrated in visual studio 2013, now how to integrate it to visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, intel-parallel-studio

I installed visual studio 2013 ultimate, then intel parallel studio 2017 cluster edition and the latter was integrated in visual studio 2013 (access, through visual studio menus, properties etc, to intel functionalities, `c++` compiler etc). Maily to use the `c++` mkl library.

Now, I installed visual studio 2015 enterprise, and I would like my intel parallel studio 2017 cluster edition to be integrated to it.

I relaunched the `setup.exe` of intel parallel studio 2017 cluster edition and saw no option allowing me to achieve this. I even repaired (it's an option in the installer) my intel parallel studio 2017 cluster edition installation, without success.

I could do a complete remove and a reinstall, but I'd rather avoid doing this. How could I proceed ?

Comment: I sadly confirm that uninstalling and reinstalling work, but that I did not find the visual studio 2015 integration option in the modify from the `steup.exe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One should not use `setup.exe` in parallel studio 2017, but rather `w_mkl_2017.0.109_online.exe` installer, which indeed allows to "Choose Integration Target", with options to integrate all available and integrable visual studios. (While `seteup.exe` doesn't.)